# error when run npm run serve (after installing vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

Reference : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start

First I run `vue create my-app` and run `npm run serve` and it works. No error

Then I want to install vuetify. I run `vue add vuetify` and I run `npm run serve`, there exist error like this :

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBvvd.png)

There exist two error :
`Unexpected trailing comma` and `Extra semicolon`

How can I solve the error?

installed features :

[fitur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFx73.png)

Answer (score 0):

Error output because it does not comply with `lint` rule.

Adjust `lint` rules or resolve them through `lint` fix option.

Example) eslint --fix

Comment: The eslint must be installed in the global. Alternatively, access the node_module path directly and run the --fix command.

And you installed the Linter and the Formatter when you configured the project. That's why an lint error occurs and the easiest way is to try in a project that doesn't use the Linterand the Formatter.

Comment: I try run `./node_modules/.bin/eslint src --fix` and it solved

Comment: but every time there is a change and `run npm run serve`, the error often occurs. so every time there is a change I have to run `./node_modules/.bin/eslint src --fix`. is there another way so that i don't often run `./node_modules/.bin/eslint src --fix`?

Comment: Acquire the skills of eslint. You can override the rules for a to prevent errors from occurring, or you can disable eslint. I recommend using eslint and you redefine the rules of eslint.